# Plotting satellite orbit on python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, orbit

I am trying to plot the orbit of a satellite around earth and the moon after using a RK4 numerical integration method for the orbital motions. But i dont quite know how display this or create the image. I kindly ask if anyone knows how this can be done. Below is the code section for the plotting;

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# We only plot the x, y components (view on the ecliptic plane)

x, y, v_x, v_y, t = Orbit(x_0, y_0, v_x0, v_y0, tmin, tmax, N)
kinetic_energy, potential_energy, total_energy = Energy(x,y,v_x,v_y)

# Set a dark background... since... space is dark
plt.style.use('dark_background')

# Create a figure and ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

# Create a yellow circle that represents the Sun, add it to the ax
Earth_circ = plt.Circle((0.0, 0.0), R_E, color='yellow', alpha=0.8)
ax.add_artist(Earth_circ)

# Plot the SSB movement
ax.plot(x, y, ls='solid', color='royalblue')

# Set some parameters for the plot, set an equal ratio, set a grid, and set
# the x and y limits
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.grid(True, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.5)

# Set Axes limits to trajectory coordinate range, with some padding

xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)
dx, dy = xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin
PAD = 0.05
ax.set_xlim(xmin - PAD*dx, xmax + PAD*dx)
ax.set_ylim(ymin - PAD*dy, ymax + PAD*dy)

# Some labelling
ax.set_xlabel('X in Earths-Radius')
ax.set_ylabel('Y in Earths-Radius')

# Saving the figure in high quality
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('orbit.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: The image shows the plot that comes out.]

Comment: But you have created an image and showed to us? So what's the problem? Doesn't line `plt.savefig('orbit.png', dpi=300)` work resulting in saved image file?

Comment: Yeap sorry i realized later on it was a matter of selecting the right initial conditions